# watch log file and extract json attributes

Tags: json, powershell

I want to be able to watch a log file, which over time has json entries added to it (1 line per json object, no whitespace). When each json entry arrives in the source log file, I want to extract an attribute from the json and append the value to an output file.

now if I read the whole file like this

```
gc test.log  | convertfrom-json | select -ExpandProperty metadata | select in_created_timestamp | out-file out.log
```

that works, giving me this out.log

```
in_created_timestamp
--------------------
2010-08-20T15:00:00Z
2010-08-20T15:00:00Z
```

but if I add -wait to watch the file, rather than read it all,

```
gc test.log -wait | convertfrom-json | select -ExpandProperty metadata | select in_created_timestamp | out-file out.log
```

nothing gets written to the out.log.

Clearly out-file doesn't play well with the streaming nature of the -wait but I don't know what to replace it with

Comment: Found an possible solution to your problem on ... https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/080672b9-573e-494e-9d92-a4765f7e6aa1/trigger-windows-program-using-getcontent-wait?forum=winserverpowershell[/link] `$file = 'C:\1.txt'
Get-Content $file -Wait | ForEach-Object -Begin {
  $counter = 1
  $lines = @(Get-Content $file).Count
} -Process {
  if ($counter++ -gt $lines) {
    cmd /c echo $_
  }
}`

Comment: `-wait` probably won't produce output from a streaming (log) file until the logging ceases or stream breaks in some other fashion. Have you tried using the `-tail` switch with get-content (gc)? That should keep the log stream flowing.